# Generalization of $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2005}=m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

I was solving the math Olympiad of Belgium the year $2005$, and the last problem was :

> If $n$ is an integer then find all values for $n$ for which $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2005}$ is an integer as well.

My question is just to generalize this problem, so instead of $2005$ , we can solve this over all $x\in \mathbb{N}$.

**My Attempt:**

If you have solved the problem you will realized that this equation :
$$\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+x}=m$$
Has solution if and only if $m\mid x$. But I am not sure if there are some other restrictions in this equation to has a solution.

Comment: This may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954501/integer-values-of-sqrtn-sqrtn2005-where-n-in-mathbbz/3954504#3954504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for non-negative integers $a, b$, the sum $\sqrt a + \sqrt b$ is an integer if and only if both $\sqrt a$ and $\sqrt b$ are integers (exercise).

Solution:

> Squaring, we see that $ab$ is the square of a rational number, and hence we may write $a = m^2 k$, $b = n^2 k$, with $k$ square-free. Then the sum $\sqrt a + \sqrt b$ becomes $(m + n)\sqrt k$, which is an integer if and only if $k = 1$.

Therefore, if $\sqrt n + \sqrt{n + x}$ is an integer, then we have $n = u^2$ and $n + x = v^2$ for some integers $u, v$.

This leads to $v^2 - u^2 = x$, which has a solution if and only if $x\not\equiv 2\mod 4$ (exercise).

Solution:

> In one direction, we have $x = (v + u)(v - u)$ and $v + u \equiv v - u \mod 2$. Hence either both factors are even and $x$ is a multiple of $4$, or both are odd and $x$ is odd. In the other direction, if $x = 2k + 1$ is odd, then $x = (k + 1)^2 - k^2$; if $x = 4k$ is multiple of $4$, then $x = (k + 1)^2 - (k - 1)^2$.

---

Explicit solutions:

If $x = 2k + 1$ is odd, then taking $n = k^2$ gives $\sqrt n + \sqrt {n + x} = 2k + 1$.

If $x = 4k$, then taking $n = k^2 - 2k + 1$ gives $\sqrt n + \sqrt{n + x} = 2k$.

Comment: +1 Apart from the limited explicit solutions, you can state all explicit solutions: If $ x = ab$, where $a < b$ have the same parity, then $ v = (a+b)/2, u = (a-b)/2$, so $n = (a-b)^2/4$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, thanks for pointing out. This comes implicitely from the proofs.

Answer (score 1):

By squaring you get $$2\sqrt{n(n+x)} = m^2-2n-x$$

On the other hand we have, by multiplying both sides of starting equation with $\sqrt{n+x}-\sqrt{n}$:  $$(n+x)-n= m(\sqrt{n+x}-\sqrt{n})$$ and if we square this again we get $$x^2=m^2 (4n+2x-m^2)\implies m^2\mid x^2\implies m\mid x$$

Comment: Is this the only restriction we have ? Because i’ve tried $x=2003$ but there is no integer solution.

Comment: This answer would be improved by finding all values of $n$ for each given value of $x$ for which such an integer $m$ exists.

Comment: @Yassir $2003$ is prime: there is no $m$ such that $m|2003$. Thus we can conclude that $x$ must be composite as necessary condition.

Comment: @Yassir Consider $\sqrt{n+2041}+\sqrt{n}$. Factor $2041=13\cdot 157$. Solve $$\sqrt{n+2041}+\sqrt{n}=157$$ and you get $n = 5184$

Comment: @Yassir When $x=2023=7\cdot 17^2$ there are two possibilities $$\sqrt{n+2023}+\sqrt{n}=17^2;\;\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2023}=7\cdot 17$$ which give $n=2601,n= 19881$

Comment: Side note: The condition that $m \mid x $ is necessary, but not sufficient. Another necessary condition is that $m \geq \sqrt{x}$.